# Passing a variable from Powershell to Python

Tags: python, powershell

I have a powershell script that is running some automation for me, as part of this I have written a script in python that utilizes selenium to open a web page, input data and exit. I need to do the same thing for another site but it has a login page. From my powershell script I am prompting the user for Name and Pwd, saving this to a variable. The part I am struggling with is passing their input into the python send_keys function. Is this even possible?

My powershell code is `$usernme = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input Username'`

Then in the python script

```
user = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""/elementname""")
```

`user.send_keys('$usernme')`

Which only sends $usernme to the field I am writing to and not the value of $usernme. Is it possible to grab this value from the powershell script and use it when I call the python script from within powershell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run the python script inside the powershell script, and extract the command argument with `sys.argv[1]`. You can have a look at [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sys.html#sys.argv) for more specifics.

`test.ps1`:

```
$username = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input Username'
python script.py $username
```

`script.py`:

```
import sys
print("Your Username:", sys.argv[1])
```

**Usage:**

```
PS> .\test.ps1
Input Username: myusername
Your Username: myusername
```

Specifically to your code, you would change `user.send_keys('$usernme')` to `user.send_keys(sys.argv[1])`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to run your selenium automation right from powershell using C# driver. Extract WebDriver.dll (from Selenium.WebDriver.3.14.0.nupkg) and put it in the folder with you PS script, along with geckodriver.exe (if using firefox). Below is a sample script you can use as a starting point:

```
Add-Type -Path ".\WebDriver.dll"
# put geckodriver.exe in the same folder

$driver = [OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver]::new()

$driver.manage().timeouts().ImplicitWait = [timespan]::FromSeconds(5)

$driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("someurl")

$driver.FindElementByCssSelector(".some-button").Click()  

$driver.quit()
```